# Are the Four Great Houses of Hogwarts based on the Four Temperaments?

Tags: harry-potter

Is there any canon information, quotes, or interviews with J.K. Rowling that suggests the Hogwarts houses are (loosely) based on the four temperaments: Choleric, Sanguine, Melancholic, and Phlegmatic?

Comment: I don't think so.  Other than there being four of each, there doesn't seem to be any connection.  Slytherine is opportunistic and clever - what would that be?  Choleric?  Sanguine?  Hufflepuff could be Sanguine, but so could Gryffindor.  Ravenclaw is full of nerds focused on knowledge.  Not sure where that goes.  Melancholic?  Phlegmatic?  Not quite either one.  Nah.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not the temperaments, but the four elements. J.K. Rowling mentions this in reference to Slytherin House:

> JKR: Probably. I hear you. It is the tradition to have four houses, but in this case, I wanted them to correspond roughly to the four elements. So Gryffindor is fire, Ravenclaw is air, Hufflepuff is earth, and Slytherin is water, hence the fact that their common room is under the lake. So again, it was this idea of harmony and balance, that you had four necessary components and by integrating them you would make a very strong place. But they remain fragmented, as we know.
>   <sub>[The Leaky Cauldron and Mugglenet](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-3.htm) - 2006</sub>

Comment: This I like.  Gryffindor is all sorts of heroic, Ravenclaw is aloof, Hufflepuff works hard, and Slytherine is full of slippery bastards.  Makes sense.

Comment: Beat me to it by like two minutes :-(

Comment: @Richard - I remembered that JKR had mentioned this.

Comment: @Richard I'm surprised you thought there was a chance against Slytherincess :p

Comment: It is worth noting that the four temperaments are traditionally associated with the four elements, but they don't quite match up with JKR's descriptions. Choleric is Fire (Gryffindor), which (mostly) matches well, as choleric people are characterized as extroverted, passionate, and natural leaders. Water (Slytherin) is associated with the phlegmatic temperament, though, which is supposed to be private, calm, caring, and tolerant. I don't think "tolerant" is a very good description of most Slytherins, though.

Comment: @KSmarts But Voldermort is very caring of himself.  =)

Comment: @Kai At least according to the Wikipedia entry on the subject, egocentrism is a trait of a *choleric* temperament. Aggression can be, too. So maybe Tom Riddle should have been in Griffindor?

Comment: @KSmarts Haha, maybe.  He certainly was brave in that he was willing to go farther than any other into dark magic.

Comment: Whatever the house, I say never judge a book by its cover. :)

Comment: Everything was fine until the Gryffindor House attacked?